# If my TempData[ doesn't exist how do I set it to a specific value

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have the following error bellow,

str = TempData["ReportName"].ToString();
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
System.Web.Mvc.TempDataDictionary.this[string].get returned null.

Here is my logic: Controller A Set a value of tempData and declare it => navigate to another controller B => TempData["ReportName"] = Value => work fine

Multiples controllers: z, y => I don't want to set the value or declare my TempData then I get an error.

Maybe I'm having an error with my syntax...

```
    report = SetDefaultsForReportObject(report, previewFlag);

      var model = new ReportResult()
        {
            ReportId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
            Report = report,
        };

      if ((TempData["ReportName"]?? "") != null)

        {
            string strPreview = "ProcessJournalPrintPreview";

            string str;
            str = TempData["ReportName"].ToString();
            if (string.Equals(str, strPreview))
            {
                report.Watermark.Text = "Test";
            ViewBag.IsDevExpressReporting = true;
            }
            else 
            {
               report.Watermark.Text = null;
               ViewBag.IsDevExpressReporting = true;
            }
          }                                   
        ViewBag.IsDevExpressReporting = true;
        ViewBag.ReportId = model.ReportId;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value may or may not exist then you just need to check if it's null.  Verbosely that may look like this:

```
string str = null;
object report = TempData["ReportName"];
if (report != null)
    str = report.ToString();
```

If you're using a more recent version of C#, you might simplify it to:

```
string str = TempData["ReportName"]?.ToString();
```

Just keep in mind that in your logic `str` may also be `null`, so don't assume it has a value set.  Or set a default value:

```
string str = TempData["ReportName"]?.ToString() ?? "";
```